# How to create a dialog box to gather user input in Fortran

Tags: windows, winapi, fortran

I am trying to make a Fortran code showing some dialog box for Windows environments.  For example, I have succeeded to make a simple "OK/Cancel" dialog as shown below.

```
PROGRAM test_dialog
!
    implicit none
!
    write(*,*) OKCancelDialog( "Continue?"//achar(0), "Test dialog"//achar(0) )
!
CONTAINS
!
    FUNCTION OkCancelDialog( message, dlg_title ) RESULT( res )
!
        use ifwin
!
        implicit none
!
        character( len = * ), intent( in ) :: message
        character( len = * ), intent( in ) :: dlg_title
        integer                            :: res
!
        integer( SINT )                    :: ret
!
        ret = MessageBox( GetForegroundWindow(), message, dlg_title, MB_ICONQUESTION + MB_OKCANCEL )
!
        res = 0
        select case( ret )
            case( IDOK )
                res = 1
            case( IDCANCEL )
                res = 0
            case default
                res = 0
        end select
!
    END FUNCTION OkCancelDialog
!
END PROGRAM test_dialog
```

But, I don't know how to make a dialog box to gather user input (e.g., number or text), like following attached image, by calling Win32 APIs (or other ways) from Fortran.

[image]

Does anyone have good idea for this purpose? It will be really appreciated if you share some wisdom (e.g., example code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you specified which Fortran compiler you're using, as some include Windows API definition modules and other helpful items. Intel Visual Fortran has modules and also a bunch of examples that can be downloaded as part of the [Intel Parallel Studio XE for Windows Samples Bundle](https://software.intel.com/en-us/product-code-samples) - see the compiler_f subfolder of that. For pure API calls, the Win32\Angle sample contains a dialog text box that it reads from, so you can study that. This should translate well (other than module names) to other compilers. Do keep in mind that the WinAPI calls are all STDCALL (on 32-bit), so make sure whichever interfaces you are using specify that.

Intel Fortran also provides a more Fortran-friendly dialog box library which can handle a lot of what you need. The sample Dialog\WHIZZY illustrates many controls using this.

Your sample code shows only a message box, which is NOT a dialog. Dialog boxes require the use of a resource editor to define the dialog, and then code to display the dialog window, wait for input, and then process the user's choices.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Your comments about examples for Intel compiler are quite helpful for me, because I use Intel compiler although my compiler is slightly older version (version 14).  Now, I have not completely understand about how to crate a dialog box in Fortran by directly calling Win32 APIs or the Fortran-friendly dialog library you mentioned, yet. I must keep to study and practice about these ways. Thank you  again.

Comment: This might be basic, but could you tell me about your comment "Do keep in mind that the WinAPI calls are all STDCALL (on 32-bit)". I use 64 bit Windows 7 or 10 systems. In such a case, what should I do any additional things?

Comment: If you are using Intel Fortran, I recommend using the dialog box support in module IFLOGM. Intel has [documentation about this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/compiler_winapp_f), but it got moved outside of the main set and you would not run across it normally. The WHIZZY sample is excellent for seeing how to use this stuff.

Comment: As for STDCALL, what matters is not your system but the platform configuration you use in Visual Studio. When you create a new project, the default is 32-bit (Win32 or x86). You have to add an x64 configuration through the conrfiguration manager. STDCALL is a 32-bit calling convention that uses the stack differently than the Intel Fortran default, so if you write your own interfaces you need to specify this. Luckily you don't have to - Intel provides what you need in the Windows API modules.

Comment: I'm terry sorry for my quite delayed response. Firstly, I will start to study about the module "IFLOGM", following your useful advices. As differently from a simple "message box", the creation of a dialog is not so easy, isn't it?  I wish there was a function to create a simple dialog consisting a message text and an input field. Anyway, I'm going to study more. Thank you very much for all of your helpful comments.

Comment: It is pretty easy using the IFLOGM routines, less so (but not very hard) if you have to use the Windows API directly. The WHIZZY sample should be helpful to you. Of course, you have to use a resource editor to create the dialog. You'll need one of the Visual Studio products that include Microsoft C++ (the Community Edition will do) to get this.

Answer (score 1):

In C, [tinyfiledialogs](http://tinyfiledialogs.sourceforge.net) offers many modal cross-platform dialogs and popup notifications (both for graphic and console mode). I am the author. It includes examples of how to call this C code from Fortran.

```
    aTitle = "a Title" // char(0)
    aMessage = "a Message" // char(0)
    aDefaultInput = "an Input" // char(0)
    cpointer = tinyfd_inputBox(aTitle, aMessage, c_loc(aDefaultInput) )
    if ( c_associated(cpointer) ) then
        call c_f_pointer(cpointer, fpointer) ! Convert C Pointer to Fortran pointer     
        string = fpointer(1:index(fpointer,c_null_char)-1) ! Remove NULL character at the end
        write (*,'(A)') string
    endif
```

*** v3.10 (2023): NEW FORTRAN interface module fully implemented with examples ***

*** v3.13 (2023): NEW PASCAL interface module fully implemented with examples ***

In Fortran, tinyfiledialogs handles char strings as UTF-8 (on windows, macos and unix).

Comment: I can confirm that the test program is very easy to compile. Just a single command `gfortran tinyfiledialogs.c extras_dll_cs_lua_fortran/fortran/tinyfd_module.f90 extras_dll_cs_lua_fortran/fortran/tinyfd_main.f90` is enough.